# MS Excel partial match sheet1!A1 with sheet2!A1 return sheet2!B1

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I need to return values from Sheet2!B1 where the string in Sheet2!A1 partially matches the string in Sheet1!A1.  I have 3000 rows of random letters and numbers in A1 with the corresponding logical data in column B1

IE:

Sheet1!A1 = aslkdj**faslkjjjj**

Sheet2!A1 = **faslkjjj**

Sheet2!B1 = realdata

I need to populate Sheet1!B1 with the real data contained in Sheet2!B1 where Sheet2!A1 partially matches the string in Sheet1!A1

This is confusing but I'm not sure how else to explain it.

Comment: Have you tried `FIND` (case sensitive) or `SEARCH` (not case sensitive)? These should work assuming that by "partial match" you want the letters to still be sequential.  In other words, `abc` would be a partial match with `xabc` and `abcx` but not with `axbc`

Comment: I see you put the `vlookup` tag on this question. `VLOOKUP` would likely just add unnecessary complexity in the situation you described, but can be a great boon in others which may at first look similar. Are you really just trying to check if the contents of `Sheet2!A1` is a substring of `Sheet1!A1` and (if true) display the contents of `Sheet2!B1` in `Sheet1!B1`, or are you trying to do something more (e.g. search `Sheet2!B` for the contents of `Sheet1!A1`, and get what's next to it.) and hoping the answer to this question will direct you to what you need for what you're really doing?

Comment: See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/371131)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you want, there's a way to do it with a helper column:

1) In Column C of Sheet2, use the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH("*"&A1&"*",Sheet1!A$1:A$3000,0),"")
```

And populate down

2) In Column B of Sheet1, use the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("Sheet2!B"&MATCH(ROW(B1),Sheet2!C$1:C$3000,0)),"")
```

And populate down

Note: if this is the correct solution, then please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1353807/edit) your question with the added info, it will make it easier for others to find it

Comment: This works somewhat.  I had to modify the column b sheet1 solution to Sheet2!C$1:Sheet2!:C$3000.  Thanks so much.  This will get me started.  I will have the occasional multiple strings to match in Sheet1!A but this should give me a good start.

Comment: @Ken A - if the answer is correct, please [mark it as such](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Is there a way to put multiple results in a single cell if Sheet1!A1 contains multiple matches from Sheet2!A1?

Comment: Sheet 2 Column A and B row 1, 2 and 3

(A1) = 0B0E6vcEj1IItcEdFVEZ0TkdHQ3c    (B1) = scan1.pdf 
(A2) = 0B0E6vcEj1IItLTl5dU1ZMG9Ba0U    (B2) = scan2.pdf
(A3) = 0B0E6vcEj1IItYkpLeWJPZUp2OTA   (B3) = scan3.pdf

Sheet1 Column A Row 1.  
(A1) = 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0E6vcEj1IItcEdFVEZ0TkdHQ3c
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0E6vcEj1IItYkpLeWJPZUp2OTA
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0E6vcEj1IItLTl5dU1ZMG9Ba0U

All of this is in a single cell and I need to convert this information into the names found in column B of sheet 2.

Comment: I'm sorry if my problem is confusing.  It's hard for me to explain my issue.  Can I attach my spreadsheet so you can see what I'm working with?

Comment: Almost there.  Is there a way to return multiple results if there are multiple matches within Sheet1!B?